# Combine data.frames of different dimensions creating duplicates where needed /r dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr

I am looking for a way to combine two tables of different dimensions by ID. But the final table should have some douplicated values depending on each table.

Here is a random example:

```
IDx = c("a", "b", "c", "d")
sex = c("M", "F", "M", "F")

IDy = c("a", "a", "b", "c", "d", "d")
status = c("single", "children", "single", "children", "single", "children")
salary = c(30, 80, 50, 40, 30, 80)

x = data.frame(IDx, sex)
y = data.frame(IDy, status, salary)
```

Here is x:

```
 IDx sex
1   a   M
2   b   F
3   c   M
4   d   F
```

Here is y:

```
 IDy   status salary
1   a   single     30
2   a children     80
3   b   single     50
4   c children     40
5   d   single     30
6   d children     80
```

I am looking for this:

```
 IDy sex   status salary
1   a   M   single     30
2   a   M children     80
3   b   F   single     50
4   c   M children     40
5   d   F   single     30
6   d   F children     80
```

Basically, sex should be matched to fit the needs of table y. **All values in both tables should be used**, the actual table is a lot larger. Not all IDs will need to duplicate.

This should be fairly simple, but I cannot find a good answer anywhere online. 
**Note, I don't want NAs to be introduced.**
I am new in R and since I have been focused in dplyr it would help if the example comes from there. It might be simple with base R, too.

### UPDATE

The **bolded** sentences above might be confusing to the final answer. Sorry, it has been a confusing case which I realised should include one extra column tha complicates things, but more of that later.

First, I tried to see what is happening **on my actuall table** and to find which suggested answer fits my needs. I removed any problematic columns for the following result. So, I checked this:

```
dim(x)
> [1] 231   2
dim(y)
> [1] 199   8
# left_join joins matching rows from y to x
suchait <- left_join(x, y, by= c("IDx" = "IDy")) 

# inner_join retains only rows in both sets
jdobres <- inner_join(y, anno2, by = c(IDx = "IDy")) 

dim(suchait) # actuall table used
> [1] 225   9
dim(jdobres)
> [1] 219   9
```

But why/where do they look different? 
This shows the 6 rows that are introduced in suchait's table but not on jdobres and it is because of the different approach.

```
setdiff(suchait, jdobres )
```

Comment: Seems like a straightforward use case for joins: `inner_join(x, y, by = c(IDx = 'IDy'))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `dplyr`:

```
library(dplyr)  
df <- left_join(x, y, by = c("IDx" = "IDy"))
```

Your result would be:

```
   IDx sex   status salary
1   a   M   single     30
2   a   M children     80
3   b   F   single     50
4   c   M children     40
5   d   F   single     30
6   d   F children     80
```

Or you could do:

```
df <- left_join(y, x, by = c("IDy" = "IDx"))
```

It would give:

```
   IDy   status salary sex
1   a   single     30   M
2   a children     80   M
3   b   single     50   F
4   c children     40   M
5   d   single     30   F
6   d children     80   F
```

You can also reorder your columns to get it exactly the way you wanted:

```
df <- df[, c("IDy", "sex", "status", "salary")]
```

result:

```
   IDy sex   status salary
1   a   M   single     30
2   a   M children     80
3   b   F   single     50
4   c   M children     40
5   d   F   single     30
6   d   F children     80
```

Comment: Sorry, for confusing you guys, my brain got fried up. And it turns out that I didn't include a separate column that is adding to the complexity and is the reason I wanted to post this question in first place. Both your answers were right based on the question. 

I have an extra column explaining which pipeline was used to produce the given result, but it happens on a few cases that both pipelines were used to analyse the same ID at the same timepoint. This produces different values only on the numerical column (y$salary on this example).

Comment: @boogie_man I saw your updated question. There is a difference in the results of both approaches because `left_join` and `inner_join` are two different joins. I would suggest you to learn about them. `inner_join` would get you common records in both the tables. Whereas `left_join` would retain all the records from left table. And there wouldn't be a match from table two, those records will have Nas. So, based on your requirement you should decide which join would be helpful in your case.

Comment: If you don't want Nas and you don't want to retain all the records of y, then I guess you should go with `inner_join`, otherwise if you can use `left_join`.